# Parsing unique but unordered named blocks

Tags: parsing, dsl, tatsu

I have a DSL where a file consists of multiple named blocks.
Ideally, each block should occur only once, but the order doesn't matter.

How do I write a parser that ignores block order, but gives syntax errors if the same block is repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to detect the error *after* parsing, perhaps with a walker.

If you need to detect the errors during parsing, then add a semantics class that stores the block identifiers and raises `SemanticError` if a block name is repeated.